# Extract multiple parts of a matrix without using loops

Tags: c, matlab

I have a huge 3D matrix and there is a loop. In every iteration, I would like to extract some different parts (for example: 10000) out of it, then the convolution between those part and a patch is calculated.

I know it could easily be done using a loop but it is very time consuming.
Is there any alternative solution to work much faster than loop?

Comment: If you know the element indices you want to extract, e.g. `idx = [1 5 21 10000]`, then you can use this `idx` vector for indexing the original 3D matrix to extract the required parts of it.

Comment: You are using Matlab right, and not C?

Comment: I would like to extract some patches out and I just know the indices of top left corner of patches so there is a matrix of size 10000 which is contained the indices of top left corner of patches! considering A as original matrix, I would like to extract 10000 patches out of A.

Comment: You know the indexes of the top left corners of all patches, but do you know their sizes?

Comment: Is the patch you use to take the convolution with the parts of the matrix you extract always the same (Meaning all parts extracted have the same size)? Or, if it varies, how do you calculate it?

Comment: Yes all part have same size and i know the size of patch, but problem is as follow:

Comment: Consider id as indexes of top left corner of patch, First i calculate i j k by using ind2sub function, Then i extract the patch from original matrix: patch=A[i:i+size(patch,1),i:i+size(patch,2),i:i+size(patch,3)], Previous step is very time consuming! Finally i calculate the convolution: convn(patch,ones(size(patch)),'valid').

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, matrix, Patch is extracted as follow: patch=A[i:i+size(patch,1),j:j+size(patch,2),k:k+size(patch,3)]

Comment: I'll post an answer after lunch

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have :

1) A row vector `idx` containing the row indexes of the top left corners of your parts.

2) A row vector `idy` containing the column indexes of the top left corners of your parts.

3) A row vector `idz` containing the indexes along the 3rd coordinate of the left corners of your parts.

We'll first have to create, from `idx`, `idy` and `idz` 3 vector containing ALL the indexes of the elements you need to extract from your matrix. Then we'll split the extracted matrix in blocks the same size of your patch using `mat2cell`, and then we'll apply the `convn` function to each block using `cellfun`.

```
Totidx=bsxfun(@plus,idx,[0:(size(patch,1)-1)]'); \\i-th column of this is the column vector idx(i):(idx(i)+size(patch,1)-1)

Totidx=reshape(Totidx,1,numel(Totidx)); \\ Creates the vector needed containing all indexes along first dimension.
```

Doing the same for `idy` and `idz`, we obtain 3 vectors `Totidx`, `Totidy`, `Totidz` containing all indexes needed.

Now we can extract the values from your initial matrix, say `A` :

```
ExtractedA=A(Totidx,Totidy,Totidz);
```

Apply `mat2cell` : `NPatch` denotes your number of extracted patches

```
B=mat2cell(ExtractedA,size(patch,1)*ones(1,NPatch),size(patch,2)*ones(1,NPatch),size(patch,3)*ones(1,NPatch));
```

Then you can apply your `convn` function to every cell of the cell array `B` : `patch` denotes the patch you want to convolute your extracted parts with

```
fun=@(M) convn(M,patch,'valid');
out=cellfun(fun,B,'uniformoutput',false);
```

Every cell of the cell array `out` is now one of the output you wanted

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very useful. Best regards:)

Comment: If this answer was useful for you, please consider marking it as accepted so that other people having the same question will know it works. I'd be interested having some comparisons in terms of calculation speed  between your old code and this one aswell

Comment: Hello, Sorry i am student and these days i am very busy! i will compare them and send you the result.